# sails-auth module gives "Cannot read property 'loadStrategies' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, sails.js

I've installed the npm module and when lifting my application, it gives the following error. I was not able to find any suitable solution in the GitHub Issues or Wiki.

The module is [here](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth). I've already included in my config directory passport.js and auth.js files, as they have noted.

```
$ sails lift

info: Starting app...

/home/me/Documents/projects/margin/node_modules/sails-auth/api/hooks/sails-auth.js:4
  sails.services.passport.loadStrategies();
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadStrategies' of undefined

at Hook.initialize (/home/me/Documents/projects/margin/node_modules/sails-auth/api/hooks/sails-auth.js:4:30)
at Hook.bound [as initialize] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/index.js:75:14
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:454:17
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:444:17
at Array.forEach (native)
at _each (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:24)
at Immediate.taskComplete (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:443:13)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:358:17)
```

Comment: Can you `require('passport')` successfully? If yes, you could use that instead of `sails.services.passport` (no clue why that isn't working). Otherwise, your module isn't accessible to the project; try installing it locally all over again.

Comment: It looks like it is a 'hard to solve malfunction': the hook expects that its services have been loaded before it gets loaded itself, which is not the case. In addition, both Sails.js and sails-auth hook are far away from there latest release 1.11.2 and 1.3.1 respectively. So, I expect that the solution from sails.js team will take time.

Till then, I'm using now passport.js directly. People interested in this alternative can find its description [here](http://younes-ouadi.blogspot.com/2015/10/passportjs-for-sailsjs.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problems in one of my sails app repositories.  I fixed it by installing a previous version of sails-auth.

`npm install sails-auth@1.2.3`

This fixed it for me.  I also updated dependency reference for my `package.json` from

`"sails-auth": "^1.0.10",`

to

`"sails-auth": "1.2.3",`

After this I was able to lift with no problems.  I created an issue report here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3385

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to use `sails-auth@2.1.1` with `sails@0.11.3`.